# Elasticsearch + Nginx + Proxy? - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I'm installing Elasticsearch on my Ubuntu 18.04 under nginx for my Magento 2.3.1. Reading the official documentation, I find the following link, and says that to configure elasticsearch with nginx on the same server I must configure a proxy on my nginx, but I am not clear if this is necessarily necessary or not, can someone help me understand the reason and How to do it optimally?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-nginx.html

Comment: ok! and an other question, if I have magento and elasticsearch on the same server, it is important to Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth? I have my server with a lot of security and nobody should be able to access my server

Comment: Elastic A) cant handle encrypted data and B) has no logon credentials.  So if I knew your server (or scanned the internet) i could find your instance of Elastic and use it to create backup shards for my system.  Bad for you but free resources for me.  You would have to block the Elastic port on your firewall if not using HTTP Auth and you dont need a proxy if running locally and not passing encrypted data

Comment: I also found that ElasticSearch documentation very unclear (like most of it )